# ASP.Net - Validate information while filling out a form?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm trying to validate a SSN number when filling out a form, and if the user doesn't match the format, it'll display an error message.

So far I got it to where you press the "Submit" button, it will tell the error, but I want it as soon as the user tabs out of the textbox.

So far this is my code

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtSSN" runat="server"/> (999-99-9999) <br>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="ValidateSSN" 
   runat="server" 
   ControlToValidate="txtSSN" 
   ValidationExpression="[0-9]{3,3}-[0-9]{2,2}-[0-9]{4,4}" 
   ErrorMessage="SSNO must be in the form 999-99-9999" 
   Display="None"/>
```

Comment: You can use OnTextChanged or OnBlur event of the textbox

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `onchange` event of the TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtSSN" runat="server" onchange="ValidateSSN();" />
```

to call this function:

```
function ValidateSSN() {
    var validator = document.getElementById('<%= ValidateSSN.ClientID %>');
    if (validator) {
        ValidatorValidate(validator);
        if (!validator.isvalid) {
            alert('The SSN is not valid!');
        }
    }
}
```

`ValidateSSN` will be called when the TextBox loses the focus, but only if the text was modified. If you want to validate the field every time it loses the focus, even if the text did not change, you can set `onblur` instead of `onchange`.